# Session timeout does not work in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, authentication, session-cookies, session-state

I have tried to use al the settings on web.config and UseCookieAuthentication() methods as indicated on many topics on the web as listed below:

[Session timeout does not work ( is set in web.config )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35862907/session-timeout-does-not-work-is-set-in-web-config)

[How to set session timeout in web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205828/how-to-set-session-timeout-in-web-config)

[mvc 5 session timeout after default period (20 mins)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22365836/mvc-5-session-timeout-after-default-period-20-mins)

However, trying to change session timeout to 1 minute (for testing) on all the options in these config or methods does not make any sense and I am not sure where the mistake is. Here are the configs below that I changed. Any idea to fix the problem? I also need to be clarified what is the best idea to set session timeout in MVC application : **in web.config** or **in Auth classes**?

***web.config:***

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" executionTimeout="60" />

    <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="1" />    

    <!-- For LDAP -->
    <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">

        <!-- Note: I also remove this part and try with only "sessionState" -->
        <forms name=".ADAuthCookie" loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="1" 
            slidingExpiration="false" protection="All" />
    </authentication>
</system.web>
```

***Startup.Auth.cs:***

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    // Code removed for brevity.

    // Configure the sign in cookie
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
        Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
        {
            // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
            // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
            OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
                regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
        }
    });            
    app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

    app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
    app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);        
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If you use `ASP.NET Identity` you do not need to use settings in `web.config`. Just add these two lines to your `UseCookieAuthentication()` method as shown below:

```
....,
SlidingExpiration = true,
ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)
...
```

So, the final code of your method will be as shown below:

***Startup.Auth.cs:***

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    // Code removed for brevity.

    // Configure the sign in cookie
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
        Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
        {
            // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
            // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
            OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
        },            
        SlidingExpiration = true, 
        ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1) //Set the session timeout at here
    });            
    app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

    app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
    app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);        
}
```

For more information please visit [ASP.NET-Identity-Cookie-Authentication-Timeouts](http://www.jamessturtevant.com/posts/ASPNET-Identity-Cookie-Authentication-Timeouts/).