# Session Timeout not working in web.config file

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, session, web-config

I am using .NET MVC 5.
I have the following code:

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms slidingExpiration="true" timeout="1" loginUrl="~/User/Login" />
</authentication>
<sessionState timeout="1" />
```

As a test, I set the timeout to 1. To my understanding, if the session is idle for 1 minute, it should automatically redirect the user to the Login page but nothing is happening. Any idea on what I may have missed?

Comment: Please [see](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22365954/1797425) if that answer helps you out?

Comment: Could you provide code how you use forms authentication on server? How do you set auth cookie during login?